# Negative Oxygen Consumption Rate

Tags: cell-biology, metabolism, cellular-respiration, bioenergetics

Oxygen consumption rate (OCR) is defined as the rate at which cells consume oxygen. I reason that for cells not capable of photosynthesis, OCR is strictly non-negative.

That was until I read this article which provides a graph with negative OCR values. Could someone enlighten me as to how this might be possible? If the cells are consuming no oxygen, I would expect OCR to be zero, not negative.

[image]

Scientific Paper:

http://www.pnas.org/content/108/33/13829.full

Comment: Start by asking if the zero in the scale actually zero, an arbitrary baseline, or a proxy measurement? in this case it appears to be a proxy so zero might not represent actual zero.

Answer (score 1):

The diagram is not clear. They should write "change of oxygen consumption rate".

The caption of the diagram makes it clearer what they are describing:

```
" In A, a time course for measurement of oxygen consumption rate (OCR) and extracellular acidification rate (ECAR) is shown under basal conditions, [...] ".
```

So basically they are measuring oxygen consumption rate under basal conditions and apply some chemicals and depict the change in oxygen consumption rate in a diagram, given in percentage.

Comment: Hi there, thank you for your answer. Will your answer still hold if the OCR was measured in units of pmol/min? (i.e. moles of oxygen per unit time)